# Create email programatically

Tags: development, web-part, email, application-pages, outlook

I am creating an application page and hence creatig a button in asp.net c# that when clicked will open up Outlook window.

I am referencing to the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook dll, and using this in using statement:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

This the code.

```
        private void CreateMailItem()            
        {
            try

            {
                var outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

                var mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

                //var mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)
                //    Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
                mailItem.To = "someone@example.com";
                mailItem.Body = "This is the message.";
                mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
                mailItem.Display(false);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }           
        }
```

I get error on the very first line, `var outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();`

The exception says:

> {"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))."}

The code works fine when executed from a console application, but not when it is executed from an application page which resides in the 15 hive.

I am using Outlook 2010, and v 14 of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, in a SharePoint 2013 on-prem environment.

Comment: Is `Outlook` installed on your `SharePoint 2013` server? If yes then have you included that dll

Comment: Yes, Outlook is installed on the SharePoint 2013 server, and the code works and an outlook window pops up if I run the same code in a console application instead of running it from an application page from SharePoint.

Comment: Check this if it's helpful in any way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477086/accessing-office-word-object-model-through-asp-net-results-in-failed-due-to-the

Comment: This is more of a C# question than a SharePoint one. Should be in SO imo.

Comment: No. Not really. The c# code executes fine, but not from SharePoint. That is why it is relevant, and why I am asking here.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things we need to check.

1. Is `Outlook` installed on your `SharePoint 2013 server`?
2. If yes then, have you referenced it?

Ways to reference the `dll` which is to be used in `Application Page` or else where

**Best Practice**: If you are making a deployment `.wsp` for your project then place this dll in your package.

1. Open up your SharePoint Project in Visual Studio, and double click on Package.
2. `Package.package` will open up, click on `Advanced` tab
3. Under `Additional Assemblies` add a new one, in your case the `Outlook.interop`
4. Build the project and deploy.

Refer the below screenshot

[image]

**And other way which I do not consider a best way, but you can try while in development environment**

1. Go to `InetPub` folder on your server, where the virtual directory of your site created.
2. Locate your `Virtual Directory`, and find `Bin` folder inside it
3. Place the `dll` in the `Bin` folder, then check again your application page.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. I added the .dll in package, and have Outlook installed on the server I am testing on. Still I get this error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas:

1. Have to tried to run he run with ElevatedPrivileges?
2. Could you try to give the IIS Application Pool Accounts permisions on the directory where the original .dll resides and see what happens

Hope this helps.